# How to shift the values of two columns with (some) same values to a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Amount1": [100, 100, 100, 200, 250, 280, 300, 350, 370, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN], 
                   "Amount2": [100, 100, 100, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 300, 350, 370, 500, 510, 540]})
```

I want to shift the values into a new column, taking the valid values where present and just shifting one of the values when both values are present.  I am thinking of mapping a `lambda x` but I've only ever using it on one column.  I have tried the following code:

```
df['Amount1', 'Amount2'].map(lambda x: x if x in 'Amount1' or 'Amount2' else np.NaN)
```

This is my expected outcome:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Amount3": [100, 100, 100, 200, 250, 280, 300, 350, 370, 500, 510, 540]})
```

Any help?

Comment: Could you post the expected output?

Comment: I think no need to complicate this: `df.max(1)` as it by default ignores `NaN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Amount1": [100, 100, 100, 200, 250, 280, 300, 350, 370, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],
                   "Amount2": [100, 100, 100, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 300, 350, 370, 500, 510, 540]})


def shift(row):
    return row['Amount1'] if not np.isnan(row['Amount1']) else row['Amount2']


df2 = df[['Amount1', 'Amount2']].apply(shift, axis=1)
print(df2)
```

**Output**

```
0     100.0
1     100.0
2     100.0
3     200.0
4     250.0
5     280.0
6     300.0
7     350.0
8     370.0
9     500.0
10    510.0
11    540.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way, without using `apply`, but leveraging [`pd.np.nanmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.nanmax.html):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.nanmax(df.values.astype(int),axis=1),columns=['Amount3'])

>>> df2
    Amount3
0       100
1       100
2       100
3       200
4       250
5       280
6       300
7       350
8       370
9       500
10      510
11      540
```

Or alternatively with [`pd.np.partition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.partition(df.values,1)[:,0],columns=['Amount3']).astype(int)

>>> df2
    Amount3
0       100
1       100
2       100
3       200
4       250
5       280
6       300
7       350
8       370
9       500
10      510
11      540
```